# Why doesn't this redirect work?

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers, http-redirect

Why doesn't this redirect work?

```
$menu = 'menu';
$item = 'item';
header('HTTP/1.1 303 See Other');
header("/{$menu}/{$item}/");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you forgot to specify which header you're sending.

Redirect headers need to start with `Location:`.

```
header("Location: /{$menu}/{$item}/");
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do `header("Location: /{$menu}/{$item}/");`

See the example at [HTTP 303 Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303)

> **Server response:**
>
> `HTTP/1.1 303 See Other`
>   `Location: http://example.org/`